# Image Stretch programmatically in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, stretch

In a WPF Application using XAML,

I created a stackpanel(width 1030) and I have 2 Images.
1. imgClient width = 784 Height = 66 and 2. imgClientExtra width =1 and Height = 66

imgClientExtra will be right end and imgClient will start at leftend.

so, the images will fit to 784 + 1 when the application is not running, the total image width is 785(784+1)..
but, wen the application is running.. the image has to stretch to 1030... with imgClientExtra will be at 1030 and imgClient will have to stretch to 1029 only..

I used stretch.fill ... but didn't work.

Currently I am using this way... is this needs to be modified?

```
     <StackPanel Name="stkpnlHeader" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="1254.662" Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <StackPanel Name="imgStkPnl"Orientation="Vertical" Width="1253.511" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image Name="imgClientPhoto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="784" Height="66" 
                   Source="D:\ehtmp_top_left.gif" Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both">

                    </Image>
                    <Image Name="imgExtraImg"   Width="1" Height="66" Margin="0,-66,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                       Source="D:\ehtmp_top_right.gif"
                       ></Image>
                </StackPanel> </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from a stackpanel to a Grid.
Set the Grid.Column definitions.
Create 2 column definitions
You can use Width to set a 'ratio' width.
For example, colA Width="5*" and colB Width="3*" means that colA gets 5/8 of the grid and colB gets 3/8 of the grid.
Combine this concept with also setting MinWidth and MaxWidth and you should be good to go.

Also, when setting widths in code, you often need to check an existing controls width by using the 'ActualWidth' property rather than 'Width' (which sometimes returns NaN).

Comment: H Darkwing.. I edited my query and added the xaml code here.. do I need to replace stackpanel(imgStkPnl) with grid to work this/?

thanks

Comment: Hi...
Just added this part.. i think I am wrong still 
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="66" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="784*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                              
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

actual image is 
|____________||_| when ap app not running,. but when I run the application it should be
|___________________________________________________________||_|

Please help
Thanks
Ramm

Comment: It looks like you have a stackpanel inside another stackpanel. This is probably pointless really. You only need one stack panel, which will stack 2 images. Then don't set any actual widths on your images. On the left image, set a MinWidth of 784, and on the right image, MinWidth of 1. If still not working, post the updated example, cleanup the example too, by removing the Name, margins, alignment, etc, because its preventing readability

Answer (score 1):

I would think that a DockPanel in your case would work, since it automatically stretches the last element (I didn't try building this code so let me know if it doesn't work):

```
<DockPanel Height="66">
    <Image Name="imgExtraImg" Source="D:\ehtmp_top_right.gif" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <Image Name="imgClientPhoto" Source="D:\ehtmp_top_left.gif"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks for the help.
I tried it using Grid. it worked out. I am posting for the reference,

Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="66" Name="imgGrid">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>

       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="66"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <Image Name="imgClientPhoto" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Fill"Source="D:\eHTMP\Exclusively_My_Work\UI_Application\Images\ehtmp_top_left.gif" ></Image>
<Image Name="imgExtraImg"  Grid.Column="1"Source="D:\eHTMP\Builds\output\WPF_Example\UI_eHTMP\UI_eHTMP\Icons\ehtmp_top_right.gif"></Image></Grid>
```